# change time format in mysql query ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am working on project where user have database with date stored in normal format **8 March 2013** and i want to sort the output with date .. but not getting right output bcos time stamp not used .... so is there way i can use or convert that date field to time stamp inside mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE year ='2012' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 20
```

i want some thing like this

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE year ='2012' ORDER BY strtotime(`date`) DESC LIMIT 20
```

but i know this wont work ... is there a way out

Comment: If your date db field is of type date, the first select should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it is not a date, use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert string to date

```
SELECT * 
FROM imdb 
WHERE year ='2012' 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%e %M %Y') DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67fca/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE year ='2012' ORDER BY DATE(`date`) DESC LIMIT 20
```